# Startup Sequence /etc/init

Tags: init

is there a start up sequence regarding configuration files in /etc/init ?

Where can found document regarding the syntax ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Documentation references

You can found all you need in [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

> Ubuntu currently employs a hybrid system where core services are
>   handled by Upstart, but additional services can be run in the legacy
>   SystemV mode.

[An introduction to run-levels](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/212/An_introduction_to_run-levels) is useful to understand SystemV

### Ordering

According to upstart manual:

> Upstart emits "events" which services can register an interest in.
>   When an event -- or combination of events -- is emitted that satisfies
>   some service's requirements, Upstart will automatically start or stop
>   that service. If multiple jobs have the same "start on" condition,
>   Upstart will start those jobs ''in parallel''.

Upstart init start/stop service based on event, this is why:

> As a general rule, you cannot rely upon the the order in which events
>   will be emitted. Your system is dynamic and Upstart responds to
>   changes as-and-when they occur (for example hot-plug events).